# Save Checkbox submit if check or unchecked with arrays

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyC6U.png

[image]

I have something like this and when a person checked a checkbox and then click the button Save, it would save the checked box and the next time the person see this table it would appear the table with all the checkboxs that the person checked or unchecked last time. How can I do that?

The months are in one array, check my code:

```
<?php

$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM utilizadores");

$month = array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");

echo '<form id="form" method="post" action="">';
echo '<table border="1" align="center">';
echo '<tr class="d0">';
echo '<td align="center" height="30" width="400"><strong>Nome</strong></td>';
for($i=0;$i<=11;$i++)
{
echo '<td align="center" width="80"><strong>'.@$month[$i].'</strong></td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
$rowColors = Array('#ffffff','#ffffcc'); $c= 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {

echo '<tr style="background-color:'.$rowColors[$c++ % count($rowColors)].';">';
echo '<td align="center" height="30" width="400">' . $row['nome'] . "</td>";
for($i=0;$i<=11;$i++)     {     
echo '<td align="center" width="80"><input type="checkbox" name="asd" /></td>';
}
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "<br>";
echo '<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Save" />';
echo '</form>';

?>

<br />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what does your MySQL table look like? when they tick the check box how is it being stored ?

Comment: That is the problem, it ain't being stored, so I would like to know how to store the information if it's checked or not. I created column named "checked" in "utilizadores", what should I do now?

Comment: of course, it ain't gon' be inserted, you don't have the insert statements.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? I'm kinda noob in php, I found this tutorial but I don't want it to save by cookies, I want to save it permanently: http://hibbard.eu/how-to-persist-checkbox-checked-state-after-page-reload/

Comment: in your current code you just selected a bunch of data, once the form is submitted nothing really gonna happen since your not processing the form, of course your gonna need to use mysql insert statement, check this tutorial, should be fairly straightforward, on insert statements: [**link**](http://www.codeofaninja.com/2011/12/php-and-mysql-crud-tutorial.html), DONT USE `MYSQL_` functions, use `MYSQLI_*` or `PDO` instead

Comment: I know how to use insert statement, I just don't know how to do it when they tick the check box to save if it's checked or uncheked I changed that part of the code that was my mistake
    `echo '<td align="center" height="30" width="400">' . $row['nome'] . "</td>";
    echo '<form id="form" method="post" action="">';
    for($i=0;$i<=11;$i++)
    {
    echo '<td align="center" width="80"><input type="checkbox" name="asd" /></td>';
    }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo '<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Save" />';
    echo '</form>';`
@kevinabelita

Comment: you should put the table inside the form, nothing gonna happen if its not inside

Comment: Ok, I edited my code. Take a look please @kevinabelita Thank you for your answers!

Comment: yes i understand, its inside now, but it's still missing a chunk of code, to enumerate what i mean, first, you need to have a table again for data insertion, since the user will input, it needs to go inside another table, then the `INSERT` statements comes in. since its in `method="post"`, you need to gather `$_POST` values process the values then `INSERT` to db table

Comment: Yes but that is the main problem of all this! How can I get the value of unchecked or checked checkbox? I know to to use the INSERT statement